# Numer of permutations of first N natural numbers

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

What are the number of permutations $P$ of first $N$ natural numbers such that there exists two indices $i$ and $j$ such that $P[i]>j$ and $P[j]>i$?

Comment: What did you try?